# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory boto3 aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am using boto3 to download a file and then copy in **tmp** file on lambda funtions . I am using this function to download a file

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME = 'dev-bucket'
key = 'uploads/random.xlsx'
s3.download_file(S3_BUCKET_NAME, key, 'tmp/hello2.xlsx')
```

but I am getting this error

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tmp/hello2.xlsx.a56DfB10'**

am I doing something wrong  here ?

Comment: Does the `tmp` directory exist? Did you mean to do `/tmp`?

Comment: @jordanm yes trying to save in that . tmp directory of lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `tmp/hello2.xlsx` into: `/tmp/hello2.xlsx`

Without the leading slash, it will go to a *relative path*.

By including the leading slash, it will go to an *absolute path*, which is what you need.